# Export to Excel in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfhttp

I am posting few inputs into a url using cfhttp and expecting to download some data in a xls file. I am trying to do get data using cffile ="write" which doesn't work.  Can any one suggest how can we go with this. Here is the code below

```
<cfhttp url="#Baseurl#" method="post" result="ExportToExcelresult" redirect="no" resolveurl="true">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="REFERER" value="#Baseurl#" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Connection" value="keep-alive" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="User-Agent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="cookie" value="TestCookie=;" encoded="yes">

    <cfloop collection="#CookieList#" item="i">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="cookie" value="#CookieList[i]#" encoded="yes">
    </cfloop>
    <cfloop collection="#PostCookieList#" item="i">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="cookie" value="#PostCookieList[i]#" encoded="yes">
    </cfloop>

    <cfloop collection="#PostDefaultCookieList#" item="i">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="cookie" value="#PostDefaultCookieList[i]#" encoded="yes">
    </cfloop>


    <cfhttpparam name="ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField" value="" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="LeftNav1_LoginView1_treeView1_ExpandState" value="#EXPANDSTATE#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="LeftNav1_LoginView1_treeView1_SelectedNode" value="#SELECTNODE#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="__EVENTTARGET"  value="" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="__EVENTARGUMENT"  value="" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="LeftNav1_LoginView1_treeView1_PopulateLog" value="" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="__VIEWSTATE"  value="#VIEWSTATE#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"  value="#VIEWSTATEGENERATOR#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="__EVENTVALIDATION"  value="#EVENTVALIDATION#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="ctl00$MainContent$repMUData$ctl00$btnExport"  value="Export to Excel" type="formfield">
</cfhttp>
```

When I do cfdump here is the the result

[image]

When I do cfdump that it is giving some binary data. For sure I am getting some data but not sure how to extract the data into xls file

Comment: Phrases like "doesn't work" are very ambiguous.  What does your cffile code look like? What happens when you run it? How is the result different from what you expected?

Comment: It is not allowing me to paste the code.. Initially I am trying to do <cfdirectory action="list" directory="#szBaseDir#/response" recurse="false" name="myList">

Comment: Not sure how that relates to a cfhttp call. If for some reason you can't post the code here, try using gist or pastebin and post a link here. Someone can edit it in for you if needed.

Comment: Sorry, iam not able to do that.. I dont have access to both the sites.. Can I have any sample code how to extract the fine by any chance?

Comment: So were you able to save the file once downloaded via cfhttp? Im not sure how or why your using cffile at this point. I'm assuming you are dumping the result variable "ExportToExcelresult" in your image. The xls file should currently binary data in `ExportToExcelresult.filecontent`.

Comment: Yes when i do ExportToExcelrsult.filecontent I am getting binary data.. Not sure what to do after that step

Comment: I am not able to save the file though..

Comment: Sounds like Excel file data is in `ExportToExcelresult.filecontent`. Just write that value to a file.

Comment: Yes the value is in filecontent.. How do you write a value to the file? It writes will all the special characters in between there is some data in that..

Comment: I'm about to write up an answer for you. Was your end goal to used the data in the spread sheet, or just to write it to your servers file system?

Comment: End goal is to write it on the server files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write the binary data to file just use the function `filewrite`. In the following snippet I write to a temporary file, but you would write to were you want to permanently store the file. I then read file back into spreadsheet object to verify that the write worked as intended.

```
<cfhttp url="http://example.com/test.cfm" result="ExportToExcelresult">
</cfhttp>
<cfscript>
    //Replace with the file path where you want to permanently store the file
    yourFileLocation = getTempFile(getTempDirectory() ,"xls");

    //Save to file system
    filewrite(yourFileLocation, ExportToExcelresult.filecontent.toByteArray());

    //Not needed. Only verifying there is a spreadsheet written to the file location
    writeOutput("Is spreadsheet: " & isSpreadsheetFile(yourFileLocation));

    //You will not be working with a temp file. Do not delete it.
    fileDelete(yourFileLocation);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: It is throwing me an error no suchfieldException filecontent

Comment: [IsSpreadSheetFile()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/isspreadsheetfile.html) might be lighter than SpreadSheetRead for validation.

Comment: @user3440782 what call are you getting the error with? Is it during the `filewrite` call? Best guess I have via a quick google search is you may be writing to `ExportToExcelresult.filecontent` witch is readonly value.

Comment: Okay Here is what I did.. <cfset testing = ExportToExcelresult.filecontent.toByteArray()> and then I am using this testing instead of ExportToExcelresult.filecontent. So I got a dump with only a Test Sheet..

Comment: @user3440782 My code isn't drop in ready for you. What dose your updated code look like? My first line in the example will not be included in your software. If your dumping my Test Sheet in your code, you using to much of the example.

Comment: <cfset testing = ExportToExcelresult.filecontent.toByteArray()><cfscript>
    //Generating data similar to your http response
    testing = spreadsheetreadbinary(
        spreadSheetNew(testing, false)
    );

    //Create a path string to a one time use file.
    tempFile = getTempFile(szBaseDir ,"xls");

    //Write File to disk
    filewrite(tempFile,testing);

    xlsSheet = spreadsheetRead(tempFile, 1);
    fileDelete(tempFile);
    writeDump([xlsSheet]);
</cfscript>

Comment: @user3440782 In theory all you need to use add is something like `<cfset filewrite(yourFileLocation, ExportToExcelresult.filecontent.toByteArray()) />` into your code.

Comment: I got what you are saying but when I open the fine, it has special characters as ..   
mm/dd/yyyyï¿ï¿½3f3ï¿½f333ï¿½3ï¿½3f33ï¿½333ï¿½ï¿½Sheet1ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½"ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½       
        
Account82011-46025CustomerKAELIN JEFFRIESMeter Bill Group        
Multiplier1ManufacturerSiemensRelative Bill MonthReading From DateReading To Date Total KWHï¿½ï¿½Atï¿½ï¿½       
 ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½       
        
dï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½MbP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190462/discussion-between-twillen-and-user3440782).

Comment: <cfset fileName = reReplace(listlast(ExportToExcelresult["responseHeader"]["content-disposition"],";="),'"','','All')>

<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=#fileName#">
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel" file="#testing#/#ExportToExcelresult.filecontent.toByteArray()#" reset="true">